# Time complexity of Count Function

Tags: javascript, time, time-complexity, big-o

I am unable to figure the time complexity of following recursive function.

```
        var arr = [1, 2, 3];
        var m = arr.length;
        console.info(count(arr, m, 4));

   var count = function (S, m, n) {
        if (n === 0)
            return 1;
        if (n < 0)
            return 0;
        if (m <= 0 && n >= 1)
            return 0;
        return count(S, m - 1, n) + count(S, m, n - S[m - 1]);
    };
```

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms) and https://yourbasic.org/algorithms/time-complexity-recursive-functions/

Comment: So you just have to figure out whether or not the function is running forever. If it is running forever, then your server / web page is frozen.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, Though I know the master theorem. it's tough to apply them over here.